# Razorpay integration in react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo, razorpay

I am developing an application in expo and used react-native-razorpay-expo for razorpay integration but I found out that it doesnot support expo. The code

```
var options = {
            description: 'Credits towards consultation',
            image: 'https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.png',
            currency: 'INR',
            key: 'test key',
            amount: '20',
            name: 'foo',
            prefill: {
                email: 'void@razorpay.com',
                contact: '9191919191',
                name: 'Razorpay Software'
            },
            theme: { color: '#F37254' }
        }
        // console.log("fh",options);
        RazorpayCheckout.open(options).then((data) => {
            // console.log("fh",data,options);
            // handle success
            alert(`Success: ${data.razorpay_payment_id}`);
        }).catch((error) => {
            // handle failure
            alert(`Error: ${error.code} | ${error.description}`);
        });
```

I am getting undefined | undefined. Can I get a solution of how to do this in android studio or an alternative to do in expo only?

Answer (score 1):

In the internal expo forum I am seeing a reply, that says that you cannot do this unless and until you eject.

This is from November 2019, and I think they have a github feature request

Please find the links here:

https://forums.expo.io/t/expo-payment-gateway-with-razorpay/30239

https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/support-for-razorpay

Comment: I tried it with react-native-razorpay-expo. I ejected the project and followed the steps and made changes in MainApplication.java but yet it did not work and the app crashed. I had to use the backup folder as that wouldn't open. I'm not getting how to go about it. Can you suggest any alternative to this or implementation of this in android studio? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you check this link https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/react-native-integration/standard/android/, but not sure it helps you

Comment: I followed the link and got this error when i ran npx react-native run-android:--------------What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Bae'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':react-native-razorpay'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up.

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2211#issuecomment-383340731

Comment: It is version3 : dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        implementation project(':react-native-razorpay')
    }

Comment: now getting this error: * Where:
Script '.../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy' line: 81

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> You need to have MainApplication in your project

Comment: i am not sure about this, but please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61700484/8437740